# Easiest way to check integer is either +1 or -1 Java

Tags: java, loops, integer, comparison

I want to the difference between two integers is +1 or -1. I think my code below is very clumsy to write. Is there any shorter way to check if two integers are just 1 apart? This seems like a simple solution, but I have 2d array of coordinates I want to check if two coordinates in the direct vicinity (either north, east, west, or south) of each other **are selected.**

Yes they are standard coordinates as the top left corner is 0,0, and the bottom right is 7,7. Essentially if one coordinate is selected, I wanted to check if there exists another coordinate where x or y differs by (+-) one.

```
//Since it's a 2d array, I am doing a nested loop. But comparison is below

int x1 = range(0,8); //all ints are range from 0 to 7
int y1 = range(0,8); //represent the current indices from the loop

int x2 = ...; //x2 represents the x index value of the previous loop
int y2 = ...; //y2 represents the y index value of the previous loop

if(x1+1 == x2){
    Found an existing X coord just larger by one
}else if (x1-1 == x2){
    Found an existing X coord smaller, and differ by one
}else if(y1+1 == y2){
    Found an existing Y coord just 1 larger
}else if(y-1 == y2){
    Found an existing Y coord just 1 smaller
}
```

Comment: What about the case where point1=(1,1) and point2=(2,2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we don't care whether the difference between x1 and x2 is 1 or -1, we can use the absolute value:

```
if (Math.abs(x1 - x2) == 1){
    // x coordinates differ by 1
} else if (Math.abs(y1 - y2) == 1){
    // y coordinates differ by 1
}
```

This works because if `x1` is less than `x2`, then `Math.abs(x1 - x2) = Math.abs(-1) = 1`.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can think of is:

```
boolean differenceOfOne = Math.abs(n1 - n2) == 1;
```

Where `n1` and `n2` are numbers.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
   Math.abs(difference)==1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Math.abs` to evaluate the difference:

```
boolean isDifferenceOne = Math.abs(x1 - x2) == 1 && Math.abs(y1 - y2) == 1
```